# Paypal Payflow error messaging vague for declined cards

Tags: paypal

When a user enters invalid payment information in our payflow checkout screen, they get the following message:

> Some required information is missing or incorrect. Please correct the fields below and try again.
>
> Error: Your transaction was approved! However, a communication with the merchant's site occurred. The transaction has been voided. please contact the merchant.

This isn't very descriptive. A customer was trying to submit a payment and the card kept getting declined (RESULT 12). The customer only figured out the payment was declined by contacting us - we had to look at the transaction history. Is there a way to return something more descriptive, such as invalid CC number, invalid CC expiration date, etc. ?

I could've sworn the error message was more detailed in the past. Not sure what has changed. I also browsed our settings and could not find anything off.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a security feature. If Paypal were to specify which fields were invalid, then an attacker could infer which fields *were* valid, and by this method, gather information about their database through many attempts to guess different fields. For example, they could discover valid credit card numbers in the DB by trying different combinations of fields and noting when no error was displayed regarding the number.

Comment: I was hoping it was the site configuration, but your explanation makes sense. If I can't find documentation on error messaging I'll assume you're right... why else would Paypal be so non-descriptive?